# how to find latitude and longitude from two another location in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, latitude-longitude

Suppose i have three station

1)  20.82741          76.459343         Nandura 
2)  (null)                       (null)                  Jalamb Junction 
3)  20.793699        76.695267         Shegaon

how to calculate the latitude and longitude of Jalamb Junction?

Any possible way ?

Comment: add some code for checking what's problem .

Comment: There is nothing that we can do. You have to decide what to do with that null values. It's your decision and your logic

Comment: Put the code which we write to get latitude and longitude.

Comment: I am using json format webservice for getting latitude and longitude but api provide some lat & lng is null. i want to put annotation on null lat lng with accurate lat lng. have u any formula for find lat lng? @Inder Kumar Rathore

Comment: If you have the address of that location then you can get the lat long. If you have just 'Jalamb Junction' then I'm afraid that you will get the exact location. Furthermore if your team is maintaining the server then you can file a bug to them Or you can just omit this value in your code and only use those POI which has non null values

Answer (score 0):

You can use  CLGeocoder class with the place name to initiate forward-geocoding requests. The geocoder object parses the information you give it and if it finds a match, returns one or more placemark objects.  To get a single address its better to provide street, city, country information if you know.